# Php Get request Peculiarity with < sign?

Tags: php, get

```
$in = $_GET['in'];
print $in;
```

When I enter `?in=<<<` its ok and it prints out `<<<`. But when you do `?in=<<<A` it just prints `<<` and `<A` part missing. What is the explanation of this peculiarity? I know that `<<` is the `T_LS` and `<<<` is `T_START_HEREDOC`, but somehow I dont understand how that `<A` is gone missing.

Edit: Sorry I got confused for a time being. My confusion came from the fact that when I eval the code like

```
eval("\$out = $in");
```

and input `?in=<<<A\nout\nA;\n` I got a T_LS syntax error.

**Sorry for my thoughtless question. Mods can delete or close this post.**

Comment: Read your question. Now do it again. Do you really think you're question is clear enough to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just like [I have edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14213808/2). `<<<A` is `<<` and start of anchor tag `<A`. So in the output you dont see it as **it creates a malformed html**. You should use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) function

```
$data = "<<<A";
echo htmlentities($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser interprets the `<A` as an opening HTML tag and therefore doesn't show it on the page, but it is still present in the source.

It's nothing to do with being a heredoc or any other PHP syntax because PHP is printing it as a string, not executing it.